# Code Conversion: EF.OrderBy as a string works in VB but not in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, lambda

`filter.OrderBy` is a string. It is assumed you will put in the name of a column.

`query` is defined as follows:

```
    Dim query As IQueryable(Of MyEntityFrameworkClass) = context.Set(Of MyEntityFrameworkClass)()
```

`filter` is a POCO that exposes a few properties of various primitive types.

In VB, this works:

```
    If filter.OrderBy <> "" Then query = query.OrderBy(filter.OrderBy)
```

The same code in C#:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.OrderBy) {query = query.OrderBy(filter.OrderBy);}
```

causes the following compiler error:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I get it that VB gets all loosey-goosey on what it will allow but what is a good conversion for this in C#???

Comment: I suspect your VB code will not compile with Option Strict On. It might be worth fixing that if it is the case as the resulting code will probably work in C#

Comment: Hmmm. It was already on but putting Option Strict On in the original code doesn't cause the compiler to choke. It's happy with the code as written. C# is still not happy, however.

Comment: Oh ok then - worth checking...

Comment: But are you using DLinq or some other 3rd party library? By default `OrderBy` extension method of IQueryable needs an `Expression<Func<T,object>>` as parameter, not an `string`

Comment: You, sir, are brilliant. It's not a third party library. It's an extension method that no one informed me about. If you pop that as an answer, I'll accept it because it explains my issue...

Answer (score 1):

The method you need to use is [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method of `IQueryable<T>`. To use those extension methods you need to reference `System.Linq` namespace.

This method receive as parameter `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>`, so to call it you need to do something like this:

```
Dim query As IQueryable(Of MyEntityFrameworkClass) = context.Set(Of MyEntityFrameworkClass)()
var result= query.OrderBy(Function(x) x.SomeProperty)
```

Where `SomeProperty` is a property of `MyEntityFrameworkClass` entity class